# Multicasting a small image with UDP via Java.

Tags: java

Our teacher is having us modify two programs in class MulticastImageSender (MIS) and MulticastImageReceiver (MIR).The only problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to get them to work properly as they are when he gave them to us. I keep being told that my address is not a multicast address.

Arguments for MIS: java -jar MIS.jar 127.0.0.0 1234 4 "/home/kevin/Pictures/ME.png"
Arguments for MIR: java -jar MIR.jar 127.0.0.0 1234

I then run the receiver first but I keep getting these outputs

Output for MIS:

```
Sent /home/kevin/Pictures/ME.png to 127.0.0.0 on port 1234
```

Output for MIR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a multicast address
at MulticastImageReceiver.main(MulticastImageReceiver.java:35)
```

Now I know a multi-cast address is 244.x.x.x with a few reserved, but I figure I need to use my local machine address to send it to myself. Or by creating my multicast socket with a 244.x.x.x address my router(computer network interface card?) knows that my address is 127.0.0.0 and by the sender creating the multicast socket with the same the router(NIC?) knows to send it to me again?

Using Ubuntu Oneric, Eclipse IDE, Java

Source:

```
MIS

public class MulticastImageSender 
{
private static final int TIMEOUT = 3000; // Time between sends (milliseconds)
private static final int MAXFILELEN = 65000; // File must fit in single datagram

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    if (args.length < 4) // Test for correct # of args
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Multicast Address> <Port> <TTL> <Image File> [<Image File>...]");

    InetAddress multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
    int destPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    // Destination port of multicast packets
    int TTL = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    // Create a UDP multicast socket with any available local port
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
    socket.setTimeToLive(TTL);
    // Set the TTL
    for (int i=3; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(args[i], "r");
        if (file.length() > MAXFILELEN)
            throw new IOException("File too big");
        byte [] fileBuffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        file.read(fileBuffer);
        file.close();
        // Create a datagram to send
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(fileBuffer, fileBuffer.length, multicastAddress, destPort);
        socket.send(sendPacket); // Send the echo string
        System.out.println("Sent " + args[i] + " to " + sendPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on port " + sendPacket.getPort());
        Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);
    }
    socket.close();
}
}
```

The MIR and its supporting thread

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MulticastImageReceiver extends JFrame 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel picture;
// Label to contain image
public MulticastImageReceiver() 
{
    super("Multicast Image Receiver"); // Set the window title
    setSize(300, 300);
    // Set the window size
    picture = new JLabel("No image", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(picture);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "Center");
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt){ System.exit(0);}});
}

public JLabel getPicture() 
{
    return picture;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    if (args.length != 2) // Test for correct # of args
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Parameter(s): <Multicast Address> <Port>");

    final InetAddress multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
    if (!multicastAddress.isMulticastAddress())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a multicast address");

    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    // Destination port of multicast packets
    MulticastImageReceiver multicastImageReceiver = new MulticastImageReceiver();
    multicastImageReceiver.setVisible(true);
    new Thread(new MulticastImageReceiverThread(multicastImageReceiver, multicastAddress, port,"No Image")).start();
}
}
```

MIR Thread

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


class MulticastImageReceiverThread implements Runnable 
{
private static final int MAXFILELEN = 65000;
// File must fit in single datagram
private InetAddress multicastAddress;
// Sender multicast address
private int port;
// Sender port
Runnable updateImage;
// Anonymous class for Swing event queue to update label
String imageText;
// Label text
byte[] image = new byte[MAXFILELEN];
// Bytes of image
boolean imageValid = false;
// True if image contains valid bytes

public MulticastImageReceiverThread(final MulticastImageReceiver frame, InetAddress multicastAddress, int port, String initialImageText) 
{
    this.multicastAddress = multicastAddress;
    this.port = port;
    this.imageText = initialImageText;
    updateImage = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            JLabel picture = frame.getPicture();
            picture.setText(imageText);
            if (imageValid) 
            {
                ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(image);
                picture.setIcon(newImage);
                picture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newImage.getIconWidth(), newImage.getIconHeight()));
            } 
            else
                picture.setIcon(null);

            picture.revalidate();
        }
    };
}

public void changeImage() 
{
    try 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(updateImage);
        // Put update in queue and wait until handled
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}

public void run() 
{
    // Create a datagram to receive
    DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(image, MAXFILELEN);
    MulticastSocket socket;
    // Create a UDP multicast socket with the specified local port
    try 
    {
        socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
        socket.joinGroup(multicastAddress); // Join the multicast group
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        imageText = "Problem with multicast socket";
        imageValid = false; changeImage(); return;
    }
    for (;;) 
    {
        try 
        {
            socket.receive(recvPacket); // Receive the image
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { break; }
        // Assume exception due to file closing
        imageText = "";
        imageValid = true;
        changeImage();
        recvPacket.setLength(MAXFILELEN);
        // You have to reset this!!!
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously,the exception message is from this line:

```
if (!multicastAddress.isMulticastAddress())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a multicast address");
```

That's because the address you gave(127.0.0.1) is not a multicast address,you can follow this link [Multicast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) to find out what's a right multicast address.

Comment: my MIR is joining my multicast, so it needs the multicast address of the sender. The sender creates the multicast, so I need to start the MIS, then instantaneously start the MIR so that the 244.0.0.x i put in it is the same so that the MIR can join the MIS?